# Query duplicates in mysql log from different threads

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

In my mysql logs i have query duplicates from different threads

```
     9517 Quit  
     9518 Quit  
220427 17:16:40  9445 Execute   SELECT `id`, `article` FROM `films`.`payments352` ORDER BY `id` IS NULL DESC, `id` DESC
220427 17:16:44  9120 Execute   SELECT `id`, `article` FROM `films`.`payments352` ORDER BY `id` IS NULL DESC, `id` DESC
                 9186 Execute   SELECT `id`, `article` FROM `films`.`payments352` ORDER BY `id` IS NULL DESC, `id` DESC
```

what is this?

I use php doctrine orm (pdo_mysql as driver) in my project.

Comment: Hard to tell. You'll have to find out where in your code it's coming from, and determine why you're getting that.

Comment: @aynber in normal case, its should not be like this?

Comment: It depends on how much traffic you have, and what queries are being run on each page load. They are different threads, which means it's different "connections", but this is a symptom, not a cause.